# System updates are broken

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates

I'm not exactly sure what the problem is, but I can't update Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I also have this error showing up: (it's transparent because I screenshotted just before the drop-down closed)

[image]

When I click...

- `Show updates` it asks if I want to download new software updates in the `Software Updater` program; however when I proceed it doesn't do anything.
- `Install all updates` I receive an error saying I don't have permissions with: `org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name': ':1.140'}): org.debian.apt.upgrade-packages`
- `Check for updates` I receive an error saying I don't have permissions with: `org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name': ':1.142'}): org.debian.apt.update-cache`
- `Start package manager` nothing happens

If I  try to open the package manager from the GUI, nothing happens either.

When I run `sudo apt-get update` I receive no errors.

When I run `sudo apt-get autoclean` I receive no errors.

When I run `sudo apt-get upgrade` it first says:

```
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 258 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
```

It then says:

```
Setting up brltty (5.0-2ubuntu3) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
insserv: Service mountkernfs has to be enabled to start service brltty insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package brltty (--configure):
    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-46-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
    brltty
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I run `sudo apt-get autoremove` I receive the following errors:

```
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 258 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up brltty (5.0-2ubuntu3) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
insserv: Service mountkernfs has to be enabled to start service brltty
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package brltty (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-46-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
   brltty
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have no clue why this is happening. How can I fix it?

EDIT: It looks like I can't access my HDD either with this error `Not authorized to perform operation`. Ubuntu is installed on my SSD, so it shouldn't affect it; but it could help diagnose the problem.

Comment: The package `brltty` is giving you trouble. Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` followed by `sudo apt-get remove brltty`. Then see if you can again upgrade and install software.

Comment: I can't run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` without the `brltty` error @Jos

Comment: Can you do `sudo apt-get remove brltty`?

Comment: Yes, and now none of the commands produce errors. I just realised that I also cannot shut down or restart Ubuntu via the GUI. Something has really messed up my PC

Comment: Just rebooted using `sudo reboot`. I can't reboot, shut-down through the GUI; nor can I open `Synaptic Package Manager`. I also have the same error before as shown in the screenshot in the top-bar.

Comment: But now the package `brltty` can't be culprit. What does `sudo dpkg --configure -a` give you now?

Comment: Nothing, no response